# SP 2010 FullTextSqlQuery display managed properties in query results

Tags: managed-property, fulltextsqlquery

I have created a managed property TaskDueDate linked to ows_DueDate(Date and Time) 
which I would like to display in my search query results.
However the query doesn't return any values for taskDueDate.

Any ideas how I can display my custom managed property?
(It looks like the KeywordQuery has the SelectProperties.Add method to achieve this)

```
string currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
string searchQuery = "select title, path, priority, assignedto, TaskDueDate" +
              " from scope()" + "WHERE \"scope\"=\'All Tasks\'" + 
" and assignedto = '" + currentUser + "'";

FullTextSqlQuery query = new FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
query.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
query.QueryText = searchQuery;
ResultTableCollection results = query.Execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention it in your question so just to make sure...

Did you perform a Full Crawl of the content source AFTER you mapped the ows_DueDate crawled property to the TaskDueDate managed property?

Do you know for sure there is content with a value for the ows_DueDate crawled property?

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was due to teh fact that the FullTextQueriable parameter is by default set to false when you create custom search properties.
After setting this parameter to 1 with PowerShell my FullTextSqlQuery returned the values for my custom search properties.

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedproperty -Identity {you id of your custom property} -Searchapplication "Search Service Application"  {In my case} -FullTextQueriable 1

Comment: - Full Crawl was done ok                                                              -There is content                                               - Found out there is an attribute (fulltextqueriable) for managed properties which is set to null by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.managedproperty.fulltextqueriable.aspx

Comment: @Wim Hill: If that resolved your problem, please add it as the accepted solution.

Comment: SOLUTION:

The problem was due to teh fact that the FullTextQueriable parameter is by default set to false when you create custom search properties. After setting this parameter to 1 with PowerShell my FullTextSqlQuery returned the values for my custom search properties.

Set-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedproperty -Identity {you id of your custom property} -Searchapplication "Search Service Application" {In my case} -FullTextQueriable 1

Comment: Can you give me the exact code, I tried this, but am getting errors. Also how do I get the id of my managed metadata property?